# Adding special character Â while reading from a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am reading content from a file using powershell. This is the file content

```
{"to":"test@test.com","from":"no-reply@test.com","cc":"","bc":"","subject":"Sales Office Access Form:","body":"<p><strong>Sales Office Access Form</strong></p>
<p>First Name: [First Name]</p>
<p>Last Name: [Last Name]</p>
<p>Email: [Email]</p>
<p>Mobile: [Mobile]</p>
<p>Residential Address: [Residential Address]</p>"}
```

Here is the code I am using

**`$content = Get-Content $_.FullName`**

When I am printing the `$content` using `write-host $content` then it is adding special character `Â`. Here is the output

```
{"to":"test@test.com","from":"no-reply@test.com","cc":"","bc":"","subject":"Sales Office Access Form:","body":"<p><strong>Sales Office Access Form</strong></p> <p>First Name:Â [First Name]</p> <p>Last Name:Â [
Last Name]</p> <p>Email:Â [Email]</p> <p>Mobile:Â [Mobile]</p> <p>Residential Address:Â [Residential Address]</p>"}
```

Why it is adding a special character `Â`? How to clean this and print whatever is in the file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: may be there are a special format in this file. i propose to replace Â after get-conent by a blank string

Comment: no there is no special format in the file @Romylussone

Comment: ah ok, so i'am wrong but try to replace as said , to see if it fix your issue

Comment: @Romylussone this is just 1 file, I have 500+ files so my concern is it might add different special characters to other files. I found using -Encoding UTF8 , the special character is not appearing. But is this the right solution to use -Encoding UTF8?

Comment: @Ahmed, i think that using -UTF8 encoding can fix it. but to be sur of your trouble , you can open some file with notepade++ and try to change encoding with UTF8

Comment: You've tagged a lot of versions of PowerShell, which one are you *actually* using? This matters because the meaning of "default encoding" changed between versions, as did other encoding support.